# React hook inheritance

Tags: reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, react-component

I'm using `Wrapper` function as multiple inheritance for `class`. `Wrapper` function:

```
const Wrapper = (SuperClass) => class extends SuperClass {
  createNotification = (type, message, className = 'filled') => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'success':
        NotificationManager.primary(
          message,
          'Primary Notification',
          5000,
          null,
          null,
          className,
        );
        break;
    ...
    default:
        NotificationManager.info('Info message');
        break;
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
class Detail extends Wrapper(Component) {
 someFunction = () => {
  this.createNotification('success', 'Saved!');
 }
 render() {
   ...
 }
}
```

My question is how to use it on `hook` components. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use hooks on class component. Only functional ones.

Comment: I'm at now changing my `class` components to `hooks`. And I want to use this function. But can't convert `Wrapper` to usage for `hooks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use hooks inside class components. But I'll try to provide a solution.

Given the fact that you basically want to be able to call `createNotification` from inside any component and if we look at your code we can actually achieve that by using a simple utility function.

Your `createNotification` function only calls a `NotificationManager` which I believe is available globally for your code (I don't see the rest of your code but I presume you just import it and use it).

So basically we can do this inside a simple function, export this function, and use it whenever we want like so :

```
import NotificationManager from 'somewhere';

module.exports.createNotification = (type, message, className = 'filled') => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'success':
        NotificationManager.primary(
          message,
          'Primary Notification',
          5000,
          null,
          null,
          className,
        );
        break;
    ...
    default:
        NotificationManager.info('Info message');
        break;
    }

// import it and use it inside any component without introducing inheritance

import { createNotification } from 'somewhere-else'

// use it !
```

If it doesn't work please provide the code for your NotificationManager and we will try to provide a solution :)